# Block progress till all values of Observable are emitted

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2, vert.x

I have slow Observable emitting Strings.
I have to block progress till all values are emitted.
Something like:

```
    myObservable.subscribe(
        a2 -> dummy.add(a2),
        e -> log.error(e),
        () -> log.info("completed")
      );

    //wait till all values collected
    try {
      Thread.sleep(3000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return dummy;
```

How can I achieve ^ result in more elegant way?

Comment: Why did you add the vert.x tag?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`blockingSubscribe`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#blockingSubscribe-io.reactivex.functions.Consumer-io.reactivex.functions.Consumer-) for this:

```java
myObservable.blockingSubscribe(
    a2 -> dummy.add(a2),
    e -> log.error(e),
    () -> log.info("completed")
);

// You will not reach here until the Observable has terminated.
return dummy;
```

This will block the caller thread until the `Observable` terminates.

Be careful about using this, though. Depending on your application's threading model, you can end up blocking parts of your application you did not intend to block, as stated in the docs:

> Note that calling this method will block the caller thread until the
> upstream terminates normally or with an error. Therefore, calling this
> method from special threads such as the Android Main Thread or the
> Swing Event Dispatch Thread is not recommended.

For example, doing this from a Vert.x EventLoop thread (I am mentioning that because you included that tag in your question) would result in blocking the event loop thread, which is bad.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help @dano .
Seems rx.Observable doesn't have blockingSubscribe().
Ended up with this solution:

```
myObservable
.toBlocking()
.subscribe(
        a2 -> dummy.add(a2),
        e -> log.error(e),
        () -> log.info("completed")
      );
```

Comment: Ah, you tagged your question `rx-java2`, so I thought that's what you were using.

Comment: It helps me anyway. Thanks Dano!